# Output Could not find or load main class in java

Tags: java

On running the code below I get an error could not find or load main class in java. It compiles without any error but on running it, I get an error on command line Could not find or load main class in java

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
class p8{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int[] ar = new int[10];
        int i, result=0, temp;
        for(i=0; i<args.length; i++){
            ar[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
        }       
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your choice");
        int Choice = sc.nextInt();
        switch(Choice){
            case 1: for(i=0; i<(ar.length); i++){
                    result = result + ar[i];
                }
                System.out.println("Sum is " + result);
                    break;
            case 2: for(i=0; i<(ar.length); i++){
                    result = result + ar[i];
                    result = result/ar.length;
                }
                System.out.println("Average is " + result);
                    break;

            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid Option");
                break;  
            }   
    }
}
```

Output:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin>javac pr8.java

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin>java pr8 10 12 23
Error: Could not find or load main class pr8
```

Comment: How do you try to run the code?

Comment: And compile? This code should run without any problems.

Comment: @qwerty: which command(s) do you use?

Comment: @user1933888: since he's referring to command line, let's assume he's not using eclipse.

Comment: I am running  this code on cmd, dos. Using the commands javac r8.java and java pr8

Comment: @qwerty: Put your command as part of question

Comment: @qwerty Use `java r8`, not `java pr8` to run it.

Comment: @qwerty: your class in your file is called p8, not r8 or pr8.

Comment: @CoolGuy: he just needs to have his class have the same name as the .java file
EDIt - and of course use the correct name in the commands

Comment: @user1933888 : you are needlessly waisting your own time by posting that. It is not relevant, and it shows an attitude that you expect nobody to be able to make mistakes

Comment: As a side node, by convention classnames are written in uppercase `p8` and variable and function names in lowercase `int Choice`

Answer (score 3):

To repeat the answer I provided in the comments:

Your classname (in code) must be identical to that of the .java file.

So, change this line:

```
class p8{
```

to

```
class pr8{
```

and try again.

For future reference, it's good practice to declare your classes as public:

```
public class p8{
```

would not have compiled, since the name of the class (in code) does not match the name of the file, while you can have only one public class for each java file, which must have the exact same name as the file.

ADDITION: Even though it is valid to have several classes in one file, the compiler will look for the main method in the class you specify, so if you run pr8, it will look for a main method in the pr8 class, not in another class in the same file.

ADDITION: Though I did not agree with the answer given by the other poster (who deleted his answer since then), if he had explained himself more, he would have had one point correctly:

Running `java p8` would also have solved the problem

Comment: Thanks man... Was stuck for about 30 minutes on this silly mistake.

Comment: I'd also add an example of the command line, because apparently the `javac` command worked for the OP, but we only have their word for it ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer: the reason his javac and java commands succeeded, was because his file was named: pr8.java, not p8.java

Comment: @Stultuske :P That makes sense